How to show finite groups are Gromov Hyperbolic groups?
Let $G$ be a finite group, I want to show there exist a $\delta>0$ such that Cayley graph of $G$ is $\delta$ hyperbolic.
As $G$ is a finite group ,so it's Cayley graph is also finite . Take $\delta$ to be highest length between two vertices of the Cayley graph of $G$.Now take a geodesic triangle $xyx$ in the Cayley graph. I want to show this triangle is $3\delta-$ slim. $d(xy)\le \delta$ if we take $w\in [yx]$ then for any point $w'\in[yz]$ , $d(w,w')\le d(w,x)+d(x,z)+d(z,w')$ . Obviously $d(w,x),d(w',z)\le \delta $ therefore $d(w,w')\le 3 \delta. $
Can you suggest another approach ? Or if you can correct my solution that will be helpful.
